# add "items_per_page" number in title tag and meta tag

Tags: 7, views, meta-tags

I created a view which has set up "Exposed items per page options." I used "24,48,72" as my options. Here is my view "Exposed setting":[image]
When I choose "items per page" as 72, the url of that page will change to "https://www.domain.com?items_per_page=72". Here is a test page screenshot:
[image]

My question is how can I add the number to "title" tag in order to distinguish "title" for SEO. There are some websites suggest to used `[current-page:page-number]` token, but this is not working in my case.  Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution. Just add the following code in template.php file.

```
function yourtheme_preprocess_html(&$vars){
    // add pager number to title.
    parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    if(isset($items_per_page)){
        $vars['head_title'] .= $items_per_page;
    }
}
```